# Python. Make asterisk graphic whith integers list

Tags: python

I can't print line with any integer from list.
I need result to be: if I have in list [5, 1, 2, 3], then it has to print:

```
*****
*
**
***
```

my code:

```
zv = []
l = 1
xa = 0
xb = 1

eil = int(input("Number of rows: "))
eill = eil

def piesinys(eil, zv):
    while eil > 0:
        print("*" * zv[xa:xb]) #<---- This is hard to do
        xa = xa + 1
        xb = xb + 1
        eil = eil - 1

while eill > 0:
    abc = int(input("Asterisk's in " + str(l) + " row: "))
    zv.append(abc)
    l = l + 1
    eill = eill - 1

piesinys
```

Prints nothing.

Comment: why the empty line? I was expecting 5,1,2,3 and there is an empty line between 5,1 and 2,3

Comment: You're not actually calling the function that's supposed to do the printing.

Comment: @mtk99 Sorry, edited.

Comment: Can you please use sensible variable names? To call a function, you need ().

Comment: Try `piesinys(eil, zv)` at the end of your code, and delete `piesinys`

Comment: @Zizouz212 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'xa' referenced before assignment

Comment: Does this surprise you?

Comment: I think yes.. Or I can say it's confuses me

Comment: @Marius That has to do with variable scope. Your function can't see the variable that is outside at the top of your code, and because of this, it throws you an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues with your code:

Add a global declaration so that your function can find the variables outside of it:

```
def piesinys(eil, zv):
    global xa, xb
    while eil > 0:
        print("*" * zv[xa]) # This is hard to do
        xa = xa + 1
        xb = xb + 1
        eil = eil - 1
```

And call the function at the end:

```
piesinys(eil, zv)
```

Comment: Again.... TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list' . And this is the main problem I think...

Comment: @Marius Hmmm... It's hard to follow the logic in your code -> Do you think you could edit your question to tell us what you are hoping to accomplish? Also, tell me if that edit fixes it :)

Answer (score 1):

Problems I see:

1. `piesinys` is the *name* of the function; to actually *call* the function you need to do `piesinys(eil, zv)`
2. `zv[xa:xb]` returns a one-element list, ie `[5]`, when you wanted the number `5`. Try `zv[xa]` instead.

I would rewrite it as

```
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def get_row_values(num_rows):
    values = []
    for i in range(1, num_rows + 1):
        prompt = "Asterisks in row {}: ".format(i)
        value = get_int(prompt)
        values.append(value)
    return values

def draw_histogram(values):
    for value in values:
        print('*' * value)

def main():
    num_rows = get_int("Number of rows: ")
    values = get_row_values(num_rows)
    draw_histogram(values)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Completed working code:

```
zv = []
l = 1
xa = 0
xb = 1

eil = int(input("Įveskite eilučių skaičių: "))
eill = eil

def piesinys(eil, zv):
    global xa, xb
    while eil > 0:
        print("*" * zv[xa])
        xa = xa + 1
        xb = xb + 1
        eil = eil - 1

while eill > 0:
    abc = int(input("Įveskite žvaigždučių skaičių " + str(l) + " eilutėje: "))
    zv.append(abc)
    l = l + 1
    eill = eill - 1

piesinys(eil, zv)
```

And again, thanks everyone who helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution will be:

```
>>> num_list =  [5, 1, 2, 3]
>>> for x in num_list:
...     print '*' * x
... 
*****
*
**
***
```